# could not understand an example in head first servlet (dynamic attribute in tag file)

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

```
<%@ tag body-content='empty' dynamic-attributes='tagAttrs' 
%> 
<%@ attribute name='optionsList' type='java.util.List' 
required='true' rtexprvalue='true' %> 
<%@ attribute name='name' required='true' %> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
<select name='${name}' 
<c:forEach var="attrEntry" items="${tagAttrs}"> 
${attrEntry.key}='${attrEntry.value}' 
</c:forEach> 
> 

<c:forEach var="option" items="${optionsList}"> 
<option value='${option}'> ${option} </option> 
</c:forEach> 
</select> `
```

so in this example from where we are getting the tagAttrs var. 
its an haspmap but who sets the values in this. and how it verifies  the correct values of attritbutes.

and also when i am pasting this code in eclipse i am getting an error on line

error is : isValid() == false `what is this, i have never this type of error.`

Answer (score 0):

The idea of dynamic attributes is to be able to pass a set of attributes, without even knowing their name in advance. The tag attributes, in this case, could be `style`, `class`, `id` and all the other standard or non-standard attributes an HTML select box can have. For example:

```
<tags:select name="preferredSport"   <%-- required name attribute --%>
             optionsList="${sports}" <%-- required optionsList attribute --%>
             id="preferred-sport"    <%-- dynamic attribute --%>
             class="inline"          <%-- dynamic attribute --%>
             style="color: red;" />  <%-- dynamic attribute --%>
```